# how to copy .htaccess to all 0777 folders

Tags: bash, shell, find, xargs

The following command attempts to copy /.htaccess to all folders permission 0777

```
find /home/*/www/ -type d -perm 0777 \
| xargs -r -d '\n'  cp -rf /.htaccess
```

am looking to run it with terminal ssh command

i search for all folders have 0777 and copy htaccess to all at once

Comment: Better solution: don't give any directory unlimited access.

Comment: right i do it , but upload folder must be 0777 so i must disable complier from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than bothering with `xargs`, you can just use the `-exec` option to `find`:

```
$ find . -type d -perm \0777 -exec cp /.htaccess {} \;
```

Comment: looking for help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978623/how-to-export-ssl-key-crt-and-ca-from-httpd-conf-apache-to-use-it-into-nginx-f

Answer (score 0):

`find /home/*/www -type d -perm /0777 -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} -r -P4 -n1 cp /.htaccess '{}'`

You want to use `print0` combined with `xargs -0` so that it can handle IFS characters.

Use `xargs -n1` so that it only tries to copy to one directory at a time.

I use `xargs -I{}` to be more explicit in what I'm doing.

`xargs -P4` will parallelize it 4 times to increased speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/*/www/ -type d -perm 0777 \
| xargs -I '{}' cp -rf  /.htaccess  '{}'
```